# hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0) not working

Tags: android

```
View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();

if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

I am getting view as an `editText`, but `imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0)` always `returns false`,

can anyone help me understand how it works and how can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextView.getWindowToken(), 0);

Can you please try like this. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try this.

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Context context, View view){
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

to call this function.

```
Utils.hideKeyboard(this, edittext);
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between this and my approach,

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work but thanks for suggestion, I'll search more, if I get a solution, I'll post here